# How to make dropper tool work across (multiple) blender windows?

Tags: 3d-view

Currently the dropper tool only works within the same window it was started with, trying to move the mouse to another blender window with the dropper active results in the tool reverting to it's inactive state. (normal mouse icon) Is this a bug or a not wanted feature?  Is there a way to achieve this via python magic?

Here's a screencast[image].

Comment: I am using Blender on Windows and if I select the dropper for the Diffuse material colour I can click on any pixel in Blender, the Animation record button(red), the Scene menu(light grey) etc. Moving the mouse out of Blender reverts it to a normal mouse cursor but I can still move it back over Blender and it returns to the dropper  and select any pixel part of the UI or not.

Comment: Hi, I've updated the post to show a screencast of what I meant. As you can see, I'm moving to another *blender* window, not outside it.

Comment: excuse my ignorance, but when I have used Blender in a multi monitor environment I have just stretched the single window over two monitors, how are creating two independent blender windows that share a single instance?

Comment: No worries man, I use the *Duplicate Window* from Window > Duplicate Window or Ctrl+Alt+W

Comment: The situation is similiar to [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/72251/30849), the answer may apply here. Have yuo tried using xmouse.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use the tool provided in that answer as I'm using Ubuntu. OS wise, I have already have the focus on hover setting enabled.